# Problems updating labels using variables from if-statements (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, settext

First of all, I´m new to both Java and programming (except Matlab), so simple answers is much appreciated :-).

I'm trying to create a temperature converter (with GUI) and I need to update some labels. That worked fine in the beginning, but now I have to use values from inside an if-statement. This results in an error where I try to update the labels:

> tempKelvin cannot be resolved to a variable

All the action happens when the "Convert" button is clicked, the code for this is here:

```
// Create and add convert button
    JButton fahrenheitButton = new JButton("Convert");
    fahrenheitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Check if input is of type double and perform action
            if (isNumber(tempTextField.getText())) {
                double  inputTemp = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText());

                // Convert from Kelvin
                if (((String) unitDropdown.getSelectedItem()).equals("Kelvin")) {
                    int tempKelvin     = (int) (inputTemp);
                    int tempCelcius    = (int) (inputTemp - 273.15);
                    int tempFahrenheit = (int) ((inputTemp - 273.15) * (9/5)  + 32);

                // Convert from Celsius
                } else if (((String) unitDropdown.getSelectedItem()).equals("Celsius")) {
                    int tempKelvin     = (int) (inputTemp + 273.15);
                    int tempCelcius    = (int) (inputTemp);
                    int tempFahrenheit = (int) (inputTemp  * (9/5)  + 32);

                // Convert from Fahrenheit
                } else if (((String) unitDropdown.getSelectedItem()).equals("Fahrenheit")) {
                    int tempKelvin     = (int) ((inputTemp - 32) * (5/9) + 273.15);
                    int tempCelcius    = (int) ((inputTemp - 32) * (5/9));
                    int tempFahrenheit = (int) ((inputTemp - 273.15) * (9/5)  + 32);

                // If none of the above was selected, it's an error...
                } else {
                    int tempKelvin = 0;
                    int tempCelcius = 0;
                    int tempFahrenheit = 0;
                    warningLabel.setText("Oops, this doesn't look good!");
                }

                // Update labels
                kelvinLabel.setText(tempKelvin + " K");
                celsiusLabel.setText(tempCelcius + " C");
                fahrenheitLabel.setText(tempFahrenheit + " F");
                warningLabel.setText("");


            } else {
                warningLabel.setText("Input must be numeric!");
            }
        }
    });

    fahrenheitButton.setBounds(20, 45, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(fahrenheitButton);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: You need to move `tempKelvin` variable outside of your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to define int tempKelvin outside the if statements and reuse it as mentioned here:

```
// Create and add convert button
    JButton fahrenheitButton = new JButton("Convert");
    fahrenheitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Check if input is of type double and perform action
            if (isNumber(tempTextField.getText())) {
                double  inputTemp = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText());

                int tempKelvin = -1;
                int tempCelcius = -1;
                int tempFahrenheit = -1;
                // Convert from Kelvin
                if (((String) unitDropdown.getSelectedItem()).equals("Kelvin")) {
                    tempKelvin    = (int) (inputTemp);
                    tempCelcius    = (int) (inputTemp - 273.15);
                    tempFahrenheit = (int) ((inputTemp - 273.15) * (9/5)  + 32);

                // Convert from Celsius
                } else if (((String) unitDropdown.getSelectedItem()).equals("Celsius")) {
                    tempKelvin     = (int) (inputTemp + 273.15);
                    tempCelcius    = (int) (inputTemp);
                    tempFahrenheit = (int) (inputTemp  * (9/5)  + 32);

                // Convert from Fahrenheit
                } else if (((String) unitDropdown.getSelectedItem()).equals("Fahrenheit")) {
                    tempKelvin     = (int) ((inputTemp - 32) * (5/9) + 273.15);
                    tempCelcius    = (int) ((inputTemp - 32) * (5/9));
                    tempFahrenheit = (int) ((inputTemp - 273.15) * (9/5)  + 32);

                // If none of the above was selected, it's an error...
                } else {
                    tempKelvin = 0;
                    tempCelcius = 0;
                    tempFahrenheit = 0;
                    warningLabel.setText("Oops, this doesn't look good!");
                }

                // Update labels
                kelvinLabel.setText(tempKelvin + " K");
                celsiusLabel.setText(tempCelcius + " C");
                fahrenheitLabel.setText(tempFahrenheit + " F");
                warningLabel.setText("");


            } else {
                warningLabel.setText("Input must be numeric!");
            }
        }
    });

    fahrenheitButton.setBounds(20, 45, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(fahrenheitButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you create a new temp variable in every if [else] statement. That's why the variable doesn't exist outside these statement(s).

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the "temp" variables out of their scope. 
They are declared in each statement of your if/else conditional statement, but referenced after the conditional statement is closed (under comment "update labels").

One solution is to declare your variables before the conditional statement and only assign them in the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your magic word is: Scope.
Because your variable is defined inside your if-statement, it actually 'dissapears' after that statement ('scope' if you will) - ends.

Just extract your variable to the most-outer scope you want to refer to it in. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You better do this:

```
int tempKelvin     = 0;
int tempCelcius    = 0;
int tempFahrenheit = 0;

if(condition1){
    ///
}else if(condition2){
    //
}else if(condition3){
    //
}else{
    //
}
```

inside if, you don't need to re-declare int function, just tempKelvin=....;

Comment: I was sooo close... I tried declaring them outside the if-statement, but I forgot to remove the declaration inside the statment, resulting in a duplicate error. Thanks for the help (and a damn fast help as well).